# Writing to CSV with python pandas module: Extra column is being added

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to get a dataset of numbers to train an AI to predict that the output should be the input + 1.
I'm using the pandas module to write to a .csv file. The dictionary: numbers is generated fine I think. However, when exporting to the csv, an extra column is added. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

numbers = {'number_1': [],
           'number_2': []}
for x in range(0, 30):
    fake_num = numbers['number_1']
    fake_num.append(x)
    numbers.update({'number_1': fake_num})
new_num = numbers['number_1'].copy()
new_num[:] = [x + 1 for x in new_num]
numbers.update({'number_2': new_num})
df = pd.DataFrame(numbers)
df.to_csv('numbers.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are getting one more index, if that's the case

Use `index=False`

```
df.to_csv('numbers.csv', index=False)
```